# Typescript - Type '[][]' is not assignable to type '[]' error

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a component that accept an array as parameter to render some data also have an array of objects (different type) that I need to pass to this component.

My component prop type is:

```
type ComponentType = {
  label: string
  children: ReactNode
}[]
```

My object type is:

```
type TemplatesType = {
  title: string
  description: string
}[]
```

I've tryed mapping this object array but it gives me the error `Type '{ label: string; children: ReactNode; }[][]' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType[]'`:

```
const maped: ComponentType[] = templates.map( ( {
  title,
  description
}) => [ {
  label: 'Title',
  children: <>{ title }</>
}, {
  label: 'Description',
  children: <>{ description }</>
} ] )
```

I've also tryed doing multiple spreading in my object array, I've got rid of error but the rendering order of data is wrong (it's now rendering: `title, title...., description, description...` instead of render: `title, description, title, description....`):

```
const maped: ComponentType[] = [
  ...templates.map(({ title }) => ({
    label: 'Title',
    children: <>{ title }</>
  })),
  ...templates.map(({ description }) => ({
    label: 'Description',
    children: <>{ description }</>
  })),
]
```

How can I solve this error and also rendering everything in the right order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of map? If it fits your needs. Should at least solve the [][] issue.

```
const maped: ComponentType[] = templates.flatMap( ( {
  title,
  description
}) => [ {
  label: 'Title',
  children: <>{ title }</>
}, {
  label: 'Description',
  children: <>{ description }</>
} ] )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to separate types for a single item and multiple items. Your  ComponentType is already an array. And when you define `const maped: ComponentType[]` you literally expect "array of arrays". That's the problem TS says about

```
type ComponentItem = {
  label: string
  children: ReactNode
};

type ComponentItems = ComponentItem[];

type TemplateItem = {
  title: string
  description: string
};

type TemplateItems = TemplateItem[];

const mapped: ComponentItems = templates.flatMap(({ title, description }) => [{
  label: 'Title',
  children: title,
}, {
  label: 'Description',
  children: title,
}]);
```

Comment: This didn't work, it now gives me the error: `Type '{ label: string; children: ReactNode; }[][]' is not assignable to type 'ComponentItems'`

Comment: @Luiz oh sorry, I've written map() function instead of flatMap(), fixed my example. As you are expecting ComponentItems - which is an array of objects and return an array of objects from your lambda function, you anyways need to "unwrap" those arrays of objects to a plain array. 
[[a, b], [c, d]] - that's what your map() function returned and that's why TS gave an error.
[a, b, c, d] - that's what TS expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating array of array in this statement:

```
const maped: ComponentType[] = templates.map( ( {
  title,
  description
}) => [ {
  label: 'Title',
  children: <>{ title }</>
}, {
  label: 'Description',
  children: <>{ description }</>
} ] )
```

by returning [{label: 'Title', cihldren:....}]. Instead, you need just to refactor it:

```
templates.map( ( {
  title,
  description
}) => ( {
  label: title,
  children: <>{ title }</>
}) )
```

Comment: This sollution gives another error: `Left side of comma operator is unused and has no side effects.`

Comment: [link](https://replit.com/join/vqxkdojvfx-nuriddinyuldash) tap here, there is a working example